# US B2 entry not stamped on passport

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration

My wife and I arrived at Newark Airport (EWR) USA on 25th April 2018 from India.

We both went through the Immigration checks such as fingerprints, scanning, etc. The customs forms and both passports were returned. On checking the passports at home, I found the B2 entry is not stamped on my passport, while my wife's is. We planned to return back to India by the end of May 2018. We are senior citizens.

What should be done now so that we do not face any problem while going or re-entry next time in USA?

Answer (score 6):

Your entry will have been recorded in a database.  You can see that and print a copy of it at https://i94.cbp.dhs.gov.

The lack of an entry stamp is very unlikely to cause a problem at any point, but if it does, you can point to the I-94 record.